# Regex - match a string, but only where the next word is not 'x'

Tags: c#, regex

If I have this string:

"The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.  What a nice brown fox that is."

What regex would I use to match the text 'brown fox' but not where the following word is 'that', i.e. (matches in italic):

"The quick *brown fox* jumped over the lazy dog.  What a nice brown fox that is."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need a [zero-width negative lookahead assertion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx), i.e.,

```
brown fox(?! that)
```

Comment: Brilliant, that does the job.  You'd get an extra point from me for even knowing what that is called...

Comment: @Paddy, if you *do* want to match `brown fox` that is followed by a word that starts with `that`, then add a word boundary after `that`: `brown fox(?! that\b)` which matches a string like `brown fox thatcher` but not `brown fox that is`.